# Simple php login - safety method used

Tags: php, authentication

I'm currently attempting to create a simple CMS (really simple).
It won't use database, but static html files.
I managed to create a php file that updates those files using form Post. Now I want to hide it using a really simple login screen.
I found [this method](http://copyleft23.blogspot.pt/2012/12/simple-login-without-database.html) which basically shows either the specific php page or the login screen.

My problem is I'm a noob in php, managing to build stuff through trial and error, and I'm dead scary of this method not being minimally safe.

I don't know much about this function, but shouldn't the login function have some sort of trim?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should at least use an SSL-encrypted connection, otherwise it's very easy to sniff your credentials.

Comment: Why do you think the login form would need "some sort of trim"?

Comment: @ Marcel how should I go about doing that? Any pointers even before I search google?
@ ScottThis is due to my noobness in php, but couldn't someone insert some sort of code to force the login?

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking of SQL injection and as you're not running a SQL database, then no.

Comment: I (highly) suggest [**you read this...**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/) before putting this LIVE – @dult.np

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I can see that I have lots to learn yet. This still beats a login via url variables right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login form you linked would offer a very basic level of security such that someone couldn't simply navigate to the page. If you're new to developing I would spend just as much time looking at the security implications of the code you write as the functionality. There are many things you need to consider.

Comment: Could you point some things to consider so I can start searching? The issue here is that to someone without programming background, it becomes easilly overwhelming to learn everything that affects code security wise...

Comment: I'm sorry for double commenting but the more I think about it the more I don't fully understand it. When you say 'would offer a very basic level of security such that someone couldn't simply navigate to the page', what do you mean by navigate to the page? You mean that we could only access a single page, and not the whole backoffice?

Comment: You say that you want to hide the page so implementing the code in the linked example would prevent someone from just navigating to the page and viewing/using it. They would need to complete the username/password prompt first.

Comment: If you need to start using a database you would need to learn about SQL injection, learn how sessions are vulnerable to hijacking if you're not using transport layer security (TLS/SSL), problems like Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) and Cross Site Scripting (XSS). There is far too much to go into in honesty but once you start reading up you will start picking up on other aspects of security too. Check out my blog for some pointers: https://scotthelme.co.uk

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that you say that tough it is safe, there are safer ways to do want I intend and instead of being satisfied with a functional code, i should dwelve more into security to fully understand what I use. Again, thanks.